# How could be method-body's parameter list have a class?

Tags: java

could not understand the working of the code in parameter list of LocationFinder.getFinder i.e. the class new LocationFinder.Listener()

make me understand what is that.

```
private LocationFinder locationFinder;
private ViewMaster viewMaster;

private synchronized void initLocationFinder() {
    if (locationFinder == null) {
        **locationFinder =LocationFinder.getFinder(new LocationFinder.Listener() 
        {

            public void newLocation(double lat, double lon, int accuracy) {
                DataModel.getInstance().setCurrentPosition(new GeoCoordinate(lat, lon, 0), accuracy);
                refreshCurrentPositionOnMap();
                if (viewMaster != null) {
                    viewMaster.draw();
                }
            }
        });**
    }

}
```

where LocationFinder is a abstract class

```
public static LocationFinder getFinder(Listener listener)
 {
     // returns finder which is reference of LocationFinder class
 }
```

and Listener is a interface

```
public interface Listener {
  void newLocation(double lat, double lon, int accuracy);
 }
```

yet ViewMaster is final class extends GameCanvas

```
public final class ViewMaster extends GameCanvas {
     private volatile boolean refreshScreen = false;

     public final void draw() {
        refreshScreen = true;
      }
```

here what does volatile boolean means ??

Answer (score 0):

1) Your `LocationFinder getFinder(Listener listener)` uses a `Listener` as parameter. The code you have shown is creating an anonymous instance of the interface and provides an implementation for the interface method `void newLocation(double lat, double lon, int accuracy);` in the class-body.

2) `volatile` is used when you have shared variables and these are accessed by different threads and provides a mechanism to let all threads see a consistent value of the variable. See the [JLS - chapter 8 about volatile fields.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)